# Passing an array as a parameter to crystal reports - "Query is too complex and unable to open rowset"

Tags: arrays, ms-access, parameters, crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2013. I get this error only if I pass array of count more than 253 as parameter to the Report. If less than 253, it works.

[image]

I divided my array into multiple arrays of count 250 each and tried to pass in to multiple parameters but the problem remains unresolved.

Below is my query to populate List

```
sql="select invoicestatus from inventory where proddated<=#"+db.dateformat(s)+"#";
db.dbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, db.dbconnection);
db.dbadapter.Fill(db.dbtable);
if (dbtable.Rows.Count > 0)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < dbtable.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       if (db.dbtable.Rows[i][0].ToString().Equals("Pending"))
        {

           arrayList.Add(dbinventory.Rows[j][0].ToString());
        }          
   }
}
```

Passing parameter to Report by

```
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("valueArray", arrayList.ToArray());
```

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: I have invoice numbers of various products which are being collected in List  through a certain criteria. Than that list is passed on to parameter in crystal report for record selection.
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("valueArray", valueArray.ToArray());
This is how I am passing to parameter

Comment: error is thrown by database.... so there can be issue with query.. can you post query if you have access

Comment: May be you have too much complexity.. that is hard to execute on database.. try to simplify the where and from clauses and check if you get the same error

Comment: @Siva question is updated for query. Issue is not with query as it populates list just fine. Rather reports works when count if less than 253.

Comment: unable to find any useful solution or idea

Comment: what is the size of the field `proddated` in database?